# I have a basic question on dart function:

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have wrote a bit code in dartpad:

```
void main() {
  greet('Jack');
  double result = myFunction();
  print(result);
}

void greet (String personToGreet) {
  print('Hello, $personToGreet)
}

double myFunction () {
  double pi = 3.1415926;
  return pi * 2;
}
```

**So, for myFunction part, why I can't do the same thing as I did for the greet function which changes the function type from double to void and replace the return keyword at the end and with a print statement to wrap up 'pi * 2'?**

**And for myFunction part in main function, can I just call this specific function directly instead of pass it into a variable and then print the variable out?**

Comment: It's the same thing written in different ways. Use what best fit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `greet` expects an argument of type `String`. That means you can't pass it `result`, which is a `double`. Instead try this:

```
void main() {
  greet('Jack');
  double result = myFunction();
  print(result.toString());
}
```

Also you seem to be missing a closing quote around `Hello`

Comment: You can also use string interpolation: `print('$result')`